# Por que minha validação de CNPJ deixa passar esse valor inválido?

Tags: javascript, validação

Estou com um problema em uma validação JS, no caso a mesma não deixa passar nenhum valor de CNPJ inválido, mas quando digitado somente 000.000.000/0000.00 ele deixa passar normalmente.

```
function ValidaCNPJ(cnpj) {

  var i = 0;
  var l = 0;
  var strNum = "";
  var strMul = "0000000000000";
  var character = "";
  var iValido = 1;
  var iSoma = 0;
  var strNum_base = "";
  var iLenNum_base = 0;
  var iLenMul = 0;
  var iSoma = 0;
  var strNum_base = 0;
  var iLenNum_base = 0;

  if (cnpj == "")
    return false;

  l = cnpj.length;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    caracter = cnpj.substring(i,i+1)
    if ((caracter >= '0') && (caracter <= '9'))
       strNum = strNum + caracter;
  };

  if(strNum.length != 14)
    return false;

  strNum_base = strNum.substring(0,12);
  iLenNum_base = strNum_base.length - 1;
  iLenMul = strMul.length - 1;
  for(i = 0;i < 12; i++)
    iSoma = iSoma +
            parseInt(strNum_base.substring((iLenNum_base-i),(iLenNum_base-i)+1),10) *
            parseInt(strMul.substring((iLenMul-i),(iLenMul-i)+1),10);

  iSoma = 11 - (iSoma - Math.floor(iSoma/11) * 11);
  if(iSoma == 11 || iSoma == 10)
    iSoma = 0;

  strNum_base = strNum_base + iSoma;
  iSoma = 0;
  iLenNum_base = strNum_base.length - 1
  for(i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    iSoma = iSoma +
            parseInt(strNum_base.substring((iLenNum_base-i),(iLenNum_base-i)+1),10) *
            parseInt(strMul.substring((iLenMul-i),(iLenMul-i)+1),10)

  iSoma = 11 - (iSoma - Math.floor(iSoma/11) * 11);
  if(iSoma == 11 || iSoma == 10)
    iSoma = 0;
  strNum_base = strNum_base + iSoma;
  if(strNum != strNum_base) {
    return false
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}

window.onload = function (){
  var cnpj = document.getElementById('reg_billing_cnpj');

  cnpj.onblur = function(){
    var valid = ValidaCNPJ(this.value);
    if(valid == false){

      alert("Informe um CNPJ válido");
      cnpj.focus(); 
      return (false); 


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: eu colocaria um `cnpj.replace(/[^\d+]/g, '')` para trabalhar apenas com os valores numéricos :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faça isto, amigo. Funciona perfeitamente para mim:

```
function validarCNPJ(cnpj) {

    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');

    if(cnpj == '') return false;

    if (cnpj.length != 14)
        return false;

    // LINHA 10 - Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
    if (cnpj == "00000000000000" || 
        cnpj == "11111111111111" || 
        cnpj == "22222222222222" || 
        cnpj == "33333333333333" || 
        cnpj == "44444444444444" || 
        cnpj == "55555555555555" || 
        cnpj == "66666666666666" || 
        cnpj == "77777777777777" || 
        cnpj == "88888888888888" || 
        cnpj == "99999999999999")
        return false; // LINHA 21

    // Valida DVs LINHA 23 -
    tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
    digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
        return false;

    tamanho = tamanho + 1;
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
          return false; // LINHA 49

    return true; // LINHA 51

}
```

Em `cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');`, eliminamos todos os caracteres não númericos do CNPJ passado como parâmetro, considerando que quem invocou a função pode ter utilizado-se de uma possível máscara no campo.

A instrução if em  `if (cnpj.length != 14)return false;` verifica se a quantidade de numerais da string (considerando-a já limpa) é igual a quantidade correta - 14.

As linha 10 à 21 checam se a string é formado apenas por valores iguais. Esta verificação é necessária uma vez que se aplicarmos o algoritmo do CNPJ sobre o número "22.222.222/2222-22" em teoria os dígitos verificadores estão corretos, ainda que este NÃO seja um número válido.

As linha 23 à 49 checam os dois dígitos verificadores, verificando sua validade de acordo com o algoritmo do CNPJ. Caso negativo, a validação retorna false encerrando a função.

Caso o algoritmo alcance a linha 51 temos um CNPJ válido e o valor true é retornado.

**Fonte:** http://www.geradorcnpj.com/javascript-validar-cnpj.htm

Comment: Está passando ainda o 000.

Comment: EDITEI A RESPOSTA

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, está implementação funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Marque como positivo :)

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma função mais compacta para validar CNPJ:

```
function is_cnpj(c) {
    var b = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];

    if ((c = c.replace(/[^\d]/g, "")).length != 14)
        return false;

    if (/0{14}/.test(c))
        return false;

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
        for (var i = 0, n = 0; i < 12 + j; n += c[i] * b[++i - j]);
        if (c[12 + j] != ((n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - n)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

Você pode testar o funcionamento e a validação no link http://araujo.cc/blog/funcao-javascript-para-validar-cnpj.html

Comment: Tranquilo. Pra mim, menos código é melhor leitura, atualizei meu gist e a resposta. =)

Comment: Pensando melhor aqui, apesar de ter mais codigo, acho q a primeira função tava com uma leitura melhor... sla, agora fiquei na duvida haha

Comment: Bele, tens razão haha! Mas aparentemente está funcionando.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas agregando um bit de melhoria na resposta do @lollipop, logo abaixo a explicação:

```js
function validarCNPJ(cnpj) {
 
    if(cnpj == '' || cnpj == undefined || cnpj == null) {
        return false;
    }
 
    if (typeof(cnpj) != 'string') {
 cnpj = cnpj.toString();
    }
 
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
  
    // (Restante ok...)
```

Fiz testes com a função passando parâmetros diferentes como arrays, objetos ou numbers. Como ocorreram erros, resolvi incrementar um pouco a parte inicial do algoritmo na validação do parâmetro:

1. Verificar antes de tudo se o valor é vazio, indefinido ou nulo. Não há necessidade de fazer nada antes disso, nem de deixar passar.
2. Verificar se o parâmetro é diferente de uma string (pode ter vindo um number, array, object, etc.)
3. Converte para string, afinal o cnpj pode ter sido passado como number, e é necessário para o método .replace() mais abaixo funcionar corretamente
4. Agora sim aplicar o replace() e prosseguir

Peço desculpas por não poder comentar diretamente na resposta dele, uso pouco o StackOverflow e minha baixa reputação ainda não permite.

Espero que seja útil. Abraços a todos!

Comment: Obrigado, Wesley.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de não haver nenhum CNPJ nem CPF com todos os dígitos repetidos, a lógica oficial de validação do dígito verificador destes documentos os declara como válidos.

Observe que não apenas uma sequência de zeros passará mas também uma sequência de *um* ou de *dois* ou de qualquer algarismo.

**O jeito é, além de implementar o algoritmo oficial, incluir ainda um *if* que invalide o documento caso todos os dígitos sejam iguais.**

Algumas maneiras de fazer isso:

```
function todosDigitosSaoIguais(cnpj) {
    var cnpj_arr = cnpj.split("");
    var first = cnpj_arr[0];
    return cnpj_arr.every(function(element) {
        return element === first;
    });
}
```

Ou:

```
function todosDigitosSaoIguais(cnpj) {
    for(var i = 1; i < cnpj.length; i++)
    {
        if(cnpj[i] !== cnpj[0])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Não costumo me importar com votos negativos mas neste caso fiquei curioso... O que há de errado com a resposta?

Comment: Essa maneira de checar os casos triviais é inclusive melhor que a da resposta aceita IMO. Devem ter negativado porque um string nao tem o metodo every e  sim um array entao vc precisa fazer `cnpj.split('').every`

Comment: @renatoargh Eu havia testado o código no console do Chrome e funcionou. Mesmo assim alterei; obrigado. De qualquer modo não creio que os votos negativos sejam por causa disso pois a outra opção funciona sempre e também teriam editado ou comentado. Se não puderam acrescentar nada além do voto eu concluo que foi mera falta de conhecimento de causa mesmo.

Comment: Então se funcionou você provavelmente testou uma versão diferente kkkk. De qualquer forma agora que você editou eu dei um  voto positivo e vou melhorar meu algoritmo para tratar estes casos triviais também!

Comment: Não negativei e também não entendo a manada, mas talvez o problema seja que sua resposta contém apenas a parte relevante e não a função completa. Ficaria melhor com o resultado final já incluso.