# Validação de CNPJ com angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validação

Eu já consegui fazer uma mascara, mas ainda não consigo validar se esse cnpj existe ou não.

O que tenho hoje é

```
 <input id="input-cnpj" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" ng-model="data.cnpj" type="tel" ui-mask="99.999.999/9999-99" ng-click="insereClass()" required>
```

Alguem sabe como eu poderia fazer essa validação? So achei em formatos Jquery

Comment: Você quer saber se ele *existe* ou se é um número válido?

Comment: E como assim, achou em formatos jQuery? Se estiver querendo apenas validar, é uma operação matemática, basta JavaScript puro. Por exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47033/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cnpj-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta que o @bfavaretto citou nos comentários, eis uma adaptação:

Estou considerando o código já dentro de um controller. E o AngularJS pode executar comandos de `jQuery` normalmente pois é feito com base nessa biblioteca.

```
$("#input-cnpj").click(function() {
  var cnpj = $("#input-cnpj").value;
  cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
  if (cnpj == '') return false;
  if (cnpj.length != 14)
      return false;
  // LINHA 10 - Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
  if (cnpj == "00000000000000" || 
      cnpj == "11111111111111" || 
      cnpj == "22222222222222" || 
      cnpj == "33333333333333" || 
      cnpj == "44444444444444" || 
      cnpj == "55555555555555" || 
      cnpj == "66666666666666" || 
      cnpj == "77777777777777" || 
      cnpj == "88888888888888" || 
      cnpj == "99999999999999")
      return false; // LINHA 21

  // Valida DVs LINHA 23 -
  tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
  numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
  digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
  soma = 0;
  pos = tamanho - 7;
  for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
          pos = 9;
  }
  resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
  if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
      return false;

  tamanho = tamanho + 1;
  numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
  soma = 0;
  pos = tamanho - 7;
  for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
          pos = 9;
  }
  resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
  if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
        return false; // LINHA 49

  return true; // LINHA 51
});
```

[Fonte da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47037/18243)

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar  uma biblioteca chamada [NgCpfCnpj](https://github.com/gil/ng-cpf-cnpj).

Veja:

```
<input name="cpf" ng-model="cpf" ng-cpf ui-mask="999.999.999-99" />
myForm.cpf.$valid: {{ myForm.cpf.$valid }}
```

Comment: essa biblioteca valida o dígito verificador ou somente o formato? p.ex.: 222.222.222-22 não é um cpf valido, ele retornaria true ou false?

Comment: fiz o teste desta diretiva e ela só parece validar o formato. Confere?

Answer (score 2):

1) Extraia os números utilizando rgex

```
var cnpj = $("#input-cnpj").value;
cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
```

2) valide o valor extraído utilizando a função abaixo 
referência: [www.geradorderg.com/logica-verificador-cnpj](http://geradorderg.com/logica-verificador-cnpj/)

```
function validarCNPJ(input_cnpj){

 if(input_cnpj){
   var input=input_cnpj.toString();
   var pesos_A=[5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2];
   var pesos_B=[6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2];
   var sum=0;
   var x1=0;
   var x2=0;
   for(var i=0;i=2){
     x1=11-mod;
   }
   //calcula digito 2
   sum=0;
   for(var i=0;i=2){
     x2=11-mod;
   }

   //test digitos
   if(x1==input[12] && x2==input[13]){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
 }else{
   return false;
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o ngPattern(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), deta forma?

```
<input ng-pattern="/^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}$/" id="input-cnpj" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" ng-model="data.cnpj" type="tel" ui-mask="99.999.999/9999-99" ng-click="insereClass()" required>
```

Comment: Isso apenas verificará se a entrada do usuário está com o formato desejado, mas, se o CNPJ é válido ou não, ai é outra história, e nesse caso, o seu código nao ajuda em nada, daí meu voto negativo. Sem falar que seu `ng-pattern` está com formato de CPF, e não de CNPJ.