# Passando o limite de caracteres o campo texto

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho uma combo "Tipo Pessoa" com as opções (1 - Física | 2 - Jurídica) e estou precisando limitar o tamanho de caracteres padrão a serem preenchidos no campo texto "CPF/CNPJ".

Na verdade, preciso validar o campo texto para quando for selecionada na combo o tipo pessoa "1 - Física" o maxlength ficar no padrão para o CPF, e assim, para o mesmo ao CNPJ.

O Form

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipoPessoa">Tipo Pessoa:*</label> 
                      <select 
                        id="tipoPessoa"
                        name="tipoPessoa"
                        data-ng-required="true"
                        data-ng-model="vm.tipoPessoa"
                        class="form-control input-sm"
                        data-ng-options="opt as opt.tipoPessoa for opt in options">
                      </select>                     
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cpfcnpj">CPF/CNPJ:*</label> 
                    <input type="text"
                        id="cpfcnpj" 
                        name="cpfcnpj"
                        data-ng-required="true"
                        data-ng-model="vm.simulacao.cpfcnpj"
                        required="required"
                        class="form-control input-sm" />

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                    data-ng-click="vm.limparSelecionados(); vm.pesquisar();"
                    data-ng-disabled="Form.$invalid" style="margin-top: 22px;"
                    data-aria-label="Right Align">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> <span>Pesquisar</span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153692/21112

Comment: @PedroAugusto só uma observação, a resposta aceita nessa outra pergunta não é a melhor opção. Tem respostas melhores pra baixo com maior pontuação

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Validação de CNPJ com angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50071/valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-cnpj-com-angularjs)

Comment: Justamente, por isso coloquei um link referenciando uma resposta melhor

Comment: Pessoal, a validação do CPF e CNPJ já está funcionando. Minha dúvida é realizar a limitação do campo texto para o preenchimento do usuário a partir da seleção do Tipo Pessoa na combo.

Comment: Você só quer limitar a quantidade de caracteres no campo? Não é muito mais fácil aplicar uma máscara? A melhor resposta do primeiro link fornecido pelo pedro augusto mostra exatamente isso, além de validar o formato do cpf ainda por cima força a pessoa a preencher a quantidade exata de caracteres, nem mais nem menos.

Comment: Isso @MáttheusSpoo, apenas limitar a quantidade de caracteres do campo texto. Após selecionar na combo se é pessoa física ou jurídica acionar o limitador (maxlength) conforme o tamanho padrão.

Comment: você pode mexer no maxlength simplesmente com `document.querySelector('#id').setAttribute('maxlength', 11) // exemplo pra cpf` ou no caso de jquery `